# What is "Staged rollout" on Google Play Developer?

Tags: google-play

When I look at the detailed statistics for my app, namely "Current installs by device" filter, I can see sections: top 10, staged rollout, beta and alpha.

I am not sure what does the term Staged rollout refer to?

It's even more strange because there are no builds I pushed yesterday and today (reasonable for today). Could this be a number of builds which were being sent to users' devices? If you remember, when you publish the app, a user does not get notified immediately, but after a few days. Google probably makes priority based on app's population.

PS. I've asked this on Android Enthusiasts, but they told me that this is a question concerned developers. If you  think that SO is the wrong place for this question, please suggest where I should post it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can release an app update to production using a staged rollout, where you release an app update to a percentage of your users and increase the percentage over time.

New and existing users are eligible for to receive updates from staged rollouts. Staged rollouts can only be used for app updates, not when publishing an app for the first time.

When you increase the percentage of a staged rollout, your original group of users who are eligible to receive the APK is always included. If you upload a new APK to an existing staged rollout, your original group stays the same. When you create a brand new staged rollout, your staged rollout starts with a new user group.

During a staged rollout, it's a good idea to closely monitor crash reports and user feedback. Users receiving the staged rollout can leave public reviews on Google Play.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Comment: WOW! How I had not seen this before?! I was releasing updates to everyone thinking that's the only way. What's worse, I've been monitoring Android Developer for each post and have never read about staged rollouts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! This announcement was made at Google I/O 2013 as part of a series of Google Play Developer Console updates, which included tips on how to optimize apps, an integrated app translation service, usage metrics and referral tracking, and beta testing.

Comment: I remember that video serious, have not watched that part at all as it was "boring" at that time :).

Comment: And if user didn't receive an update durin a staged rollout, is it possible to enter the google play and update it manually?

Comment: @mes I don't think so. Just now one of my devices updated an app, but the others not. If I browse the Play Store, I only see the old version. The new one is apparently visible only to the selected users in the staged release.

Comment: So where are the staged rollout options on the Google Developer Console? When I click 'start rollout to Alpha/Beta', it just does it, so I'm reluctant to click 'start rollout to production', but are the options hiding behind there?

Comment: @controlbox Yes, you can use staged rollout only for production. It's there in the last step of creating a production release.

Comment: Let's say roll out for 20% when these 20% users updated their app, would it increment automatically until 100%? Or we must increment it manually?

Comment: If you're rolling out your first release, you won't see the option to select a rollout percentage. Only in successive rollouts you can choose to do staged rollout. And this is also possible for beta rollouts. Check step 3 point 8 here : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en

Comment: how long does it take for the roll out to be in effect?

Comment: Hello! If a new user and there stage rollout? What would I get? The old version or the new version?

Comment: @NeonWarge New installs will receive the old version until the staged rollout is at 100%.